# unable to insert rows in a new table in sql, getting error as string or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have the below table created

```
create table person
(
sno int primary key identity(1,1) not null,
firstname nvarchar,
lastname nvarchar,
city nvarchar,
zip int
);
```

I have written the insert statement as

```
insert into person
(firstname,lastname,city,zip)
values
('firstname','lastname','city','123456')
```

but i am getting the following error when i  try to insert values into the table

```
string or binary data would be truncated
The statement has been terminated
```

Please help to overcome my problem , i am not sure where i did i went wrong.

Please help,

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: you have declared `zip` as int, but tried to insert a value of `varchar`. try `values('firstname','lastname','city',123456)` (no quotes for zip)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you see this error 
**`string or binary data would be truncated` its a column length`** issue.

Check the length of the column in the sql field definition

You are trying to `insert data of more length than the field length`

So **`either you limit the data to the length in database or increase the column length.`**

Comment: Thanks I have modified the  table columns field definition to varchar(50) rather than nvarchar. Now i am able to insert values into the table.Thanks Rex.

Comment: @SaghirA.Khatri I didn't think that making text bigger will be referred as shouting, nay ways made it normal :)

Answer (score 1):

in your script there are 2 issues:

1. You did not specify the length of the `varchar` columns.
   Take a look [here](http://www.ubitsoft.com/products/sqlenlight/help_19/html/ec68d798-5578-456f-a132-852949cc680e.htm).

> Do not define columns, variables and parameters using VARCHAR, and
>   NVARCHAR data types without specifying length attribute. This will not
>   produce a dynamic length string data, but will make SQL Server choose
>   default length of 1 (NOTE: In some scenarios it the length can be 30).

Replace it with:

```
create table person
(
sno int primary key identity(1,1) not null,
firstname nvarchar(50),
lastname nvarchar(50),
city nvarchar(50),
zip int
);
```

2..You are attempting to insert a `varchar` zip rather as `int` (which is the columns type).
Replace the insert with:

```
insert into person
(firstname,lastname,city,zip)
values
('firstname','lastname','city',123456)
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the **real** problem - `varchar` definition without a length, which results in a `Varchar(1)` column ...

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting a string for an int (zip), try this:

```
insert into person
(firstname,lastname,city,zip)
values
('firstname','lastname','city',123456)
```

EDIT:

you should also declare your nvarchar length as it only creates it as a nvarchar(1) if you don't , so change all of your nvarchar's to nvarchar(50) or whatever length you want for max

Per TSQL Technet Article on NVARCHAR:

`nvarchar[(n)]: When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified with the CAST function, the default length is 30.`

Comment: Care to comment on reason for -1, anonymous downvoter?